# SQL query to DateTime value if user default language is unknown

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table in database with column of `DateTime` type.
Currently when I need filtering by this column I'm using comparison with date in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format that is valid for English locale, but if default locale for user in database is German for example, format should be `YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS` and my query is failing.

I didn't find any solution to convert a timestamp to a DateTime without specifying date format.

Also I was trying to convert DateTime to Timestamp (to have possibility to make comparison with timestamp value) but for some reasons this isn't works.

Example(MS SQL SERVER):

I have two columns in a table:

ID | CREATEDDATE

---

1 | 2017-10-23 10:00:00.000

---

2 | 2017-10-25 10:00:00.000

If for user default language is set to English query

`SELECT * from TABLE WHERE CREATEDDATE > '2017-10-24 10:00:00'`

returns me second row, but if default language is set to German I have error with such message:

`Bei der Konvertierung eines varchar-Datentyps in einen datetime-Datentyp liegt der Wert außerhalb des gültigen Bereichs`

I need some how change my query to get possibility not to worry about user default language.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag only with the database you are using.  Oracle and SQL Server are quite different.

Comment: It is better to always check in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format

Comment: @Dmitrij Kultasev the problem is that data in column has 'yyyy-mm-dd' format but after changing of default language for use in data base when you will try to search with filter like this `WHERE CREATEDDATE > '2017-10-23 10:00:00'` you will get error

Comment: A `date` column does **not** have "a format" (regardless of the DBMS being used - which we still don't know)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server converts strings in the following formats to date/times, regardless of internationalization settings:

- `YYYYMMDD` for dates
- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS` with decimals allowed after the seconds.

These formats are quite specific, but are independent of internationalization, as explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql#ansi-and-iso-8601-compliance):

> The advantage in using the ISO 8601 format is that it is an
>   international standard with unambiguous specification. Also, this
>   format is not affected by the `SET DATEFORMAT` or `SET LANGUAGE` setting.

Note that although I prefer `YYYY-MM-DD`, SQL Server does have internationalization settings that interpret this as YYYY-DD-MM, so YYYYMMDD is safer.  I prefer `YYYY-MM-DD` because it is (also) ISO standard, used across most databases, easier to read, and the risk of confusion is relatively small.

In Oracle, you can use the `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` keywords:

- `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'` for dates
- `TIMESTAMP 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` with decimals allowed after the seconds.

Comment: As I say `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` is actual for English locale, if you set German it will be  `YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS` checked for MsSql

Comment: I'm telling not about system locale, problem is observed after changing default locale for user in Database

Comment: @VitaliiMuzalevskyi . . . I fixed the format.  It is independent of internationalization, if formatted correctly.

Comment: Thank you guys, it's really strange behaviour but `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS` and `YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS` formats works fine